Calling Dynamics from APIM with Managed Identities
we've started to work with Azure APIM and Dynamics on Dataverse.
I was asked to create an API in the APIM that returns content of some tables from the dataverse using managed identities.
I requested a new identity to our tenant administrator.
The APIM already had a system assigned, managed identity but I added the new identity as a user assigned identity.
I went to security settings of our Dynamics instance, created a new security role to which I gave read access to some tables.
I assigned this role to the new identity.
In my APIM resource, I created a product to which I've added an inbound policy:
    <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://....dynamics.com" client-id="..." output-token-variable-name="msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["msi-access-token"])</value>
    </set-header>

I assigned the product to a new API (dv) and added a method (items) that calls the WhoAmI method of the dataverse.
When I call the API, I get the message: "The user is not a member of the organization."
Am I right to think that doing as above with authentication-managed-identity, the API calls the dataverse as this Managed Identity ?
Could I have also used a System assign identity ?
Any idea why the user is not recognized ?
This new API will be called from postman likes, hence I couldn't use the client id of a caller like, an Azure Function, I would need to run GET queries from a browser and get content of a table passed in the query string like: https://q.acme.com/dv/items/contacts.  Is that possible ?
